# SwitchPreference.isEnabled() not detecting if enabled/disabled properly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, switchpreference

I'm trying to use `SwitchPreference` and trying to detect it's state using `isEnabled()` method.

Here's the code (in `SettingsActivity.java`):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        spChanged = new
                SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                          String key) {
                        // your stuff here
                        if (key.equals(KEY_ENABLE_F)) {
                            SwitchPreference fPref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(key);
                            if (fPref.isEnabled()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged);
    }
```

The problem is that the `Toast` with text "Enabled" is showing up no matter if switch in 'ON' or 'OFF'.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops! I should have tried it before posting the question. Anyways, I solved the issue by changing:

```
fPref.isEnabled()
```

to this:

```
fPref.isChecked()
```